# Contenteditable div Enter issue (keyCode 13)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Enter in the Contenteditable "div" tag makes it creates a new "div" tag. 
How can I do so that it instead creates a "p", if you hit enter after  an "img" tag?

```
<div id="append_id" contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
    <img style="height:100px;" src="myImage.jpg" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3uTmW/3/

Comment: This is an duplicate, [check out this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023307/dealing-with-line-breaks-on-contenteditable-div)

Comment: If, you've a code for creating the `img` element, you could create a `p` element within the same code...

Comment: Teemu: If a user clicks the enter but do nothing else it's a bit silly to have p where

Comment: Arko Elsenaar: Thank you, that I had not seen, but it has no answer marked as answer. I naturally want to have the least amount of code for this. Pluss i want ONLY trigger this AFTER a IMG tag or on a IMG tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default paragraph can be specified in chrome by using:

```
document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p')
```

See [how to change behavior of contenteditable blocks after on enter pressed in various browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735672/how-to-change-behavior-of-contenteditable-blocks-after-on-enter-pressed-in-vario).